# Post some content from website to Facebook page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create a website which will allow user to login with his/her Facebook credentials. Now, my website would allow user to post some content (text plus images) and also if user posts it on my website, it should also be posted on a page (which is also created and owned by me).

Is it possible to do that? If yes, can anyone point to any resource which explains how to do it?

Comment: right now this is way too broad for stackoverflow, please hit the official docs first and do some programming and testing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very easy task, you must rely on some facebook SDK, more precise, you need to choose a library that offers wrapping classes around FB Graph Api i.e. **Api Client**.

This being said, check the following links as a start and continue developing according to your application requirements.

- https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook

P.S: the library you choose must support **OAuth**, and you should read more about this protocol.